# BlocListener not being updated for unknown reason

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

I'm facing some very strange issue with BLoC. I'm doing something that isn't considered best practice (sharing data between cubits), however I believe the cubit should still work as expected.

I have this method activate() in SelectMultipleCubit:

```
class SelectMultipleCubit extends Cubit<SelectMultipleState> {
  SelectMultipleCubit(this.folderViewCubit, this.fileExplorerCubit) : super(SelectMultipleInitial());

  final FolderViewCubit folderViewCubit;
  final FileExplorerCubit fileExplorerCubit;
```

Here is the modified version of `activate()`:

```
void activate(ListItem selectedItem) async {
    emit(SelectMultipleLoading());

    try {
      // Get the parent ID and type of the selected item
      String parentId;
      dynamic selectedObject;

      if (selectedItem.item is Folder) {
        parentId = (selectedItem.item as Folder).parentId;
        selectedObject = selectedItem.item as Folder;
      } else if (selectedItem.item is Receipt) {
        parentId = (selectedItem.item as Receipt).parentId;
        selectedObject = selectedItem.item as Receipt;
      } else {
        emit(SelectMultipleError());
        return;
      }

      List<Object> items = List.from(folderViewCubit.cachedCurrentlyDisplayedFiles);

      // Remove the selected item from the list
      items.removeWhere((element) {
        if (element is Folder && selectedObject is Folder) {
          return element.id == selectedObject.id;
        } else if (element is Receipt && selectedObject is Receipt) {
          return element.id == selectedObject.id;
        }
        return false;
      });

      print('items: ${items.length}');

      // Convert items to ListItems
      List<ListItem> listItems =
          items.map((item) => ListItem(item: item)).toList();

      print('listItems: ${listItems.length}');

      emit(SelectMultipleActivated(
          items: listItems, initiallySelectedItem: selectedItem));
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      emit(SelectMultipleError());
    }
  }
```

Here is the original version of `activate()` which doesn't use cached files from the other cubit.

```
void activate(ListItem selectedItem) async {
    emit(SelectMultipleLoading());

    try {
      // Get the parent ID and type of the selected item
      String parentId;
      dynamic selectedObject;

      if (selectedItem.item is Folder) {
        parentId = (selectedItem.item as Folder).parentId;
        selectedObject = selectedItem.item as Folder;
      } else if (selectedItem.item is Receipt) {
        parentId = (selectedItem.item as Receipt).parentId;
        selectedObject = selectedItem.item as Receipt;
      } else {
        emit(SelectMultipleError());
        return;
      }

// setting last order & column values
      final String lastColumn = _prefs.getLastColumn();
      final String lastOrder = _prefs.getLastOrder();

      List<Object> items;

      switch (lastColumn) {
        case 'price':
          final List<FolderWithPrice> foldersWithPrice = await DatabaseRepository.instance.getFoldersByPrice(parentId, lastOrder);
          final List<ReceiptWithPrice> receiptsWithPrices = await DatabaseRepository.instance.getReceiptsByPrice(parentId, lastOrder);
          items = [...foldersWithPrice, ...receiptsWithPrices];
          break;
        case 'storageSize':
          final List<FolderWithSize> foldersWithSize = await DatabaseRepository.instance.getFoldersByTotalReceiptSize(parentId, lastOrder);
          final List<ReceiptWithSize> receiptsWithSize =  await DatabaseRepository.instance.getReceiptsBySize(parentId, lastOrder);
          items = [...foldersWithSize, ...receiptsWithSize];
          break;
        default:
          final List<Folder> folders = await DatabaseRepository.instance.getFoldersInFolderSortedBy(parentId, lastColumn, lastOrder);
          final List<Receipt> receipts = await DatabaseRepository.instance.getReceiptsInFolderSortedBy(parentId, lastColumn, lastOrder);
          items = [...folders, ...receipts];
          break;
      }

      // Remove the selected item from the list
      items.removeWhere((element) {
        if (element is Folder && selectedObject is Folder) {
          return element.id == selectedObject.id;
        } else if (element is Receipt && selectedObject is Receipt) {
          return element.id == selectedObject.id;
        }
        return false;
      });

      // Convert items to ListItems
      List<ListItem> listItems =
          items.map((item) => ListItem(item: item)).toList();

      emit(SelectMultipleActivated(
          items: listItems, initiallySelectedItem: selectedItem));
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Now in my UI I have this BlocListener tp populate a list of selectable items:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<SelectMultipleCubit, SelectMultipleState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is SelectMultipleActivated) {
          // this code should only run once, when the SelectMultipleView is setup
          // currently SelectMultipleActivated is only emitted once so it is fine
          final initiallySelectedListItem = state.initiallySelectedItem;
          final restOfListItems = state.items;
          // adding initially selected item to currentlySelectedListItems
          currentlySelectedListItemsNotifier.value.add(initiallySelectedListItem);
          // adding initially selected item to allItems first
          allItems.add(initiallySelectedListItem);
          // adding rest of folder contents to allItems
          allItems.addAll(restOfListItems);
        }
        if (state is SelectMultipleActionSuccess) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      },
```

I have discovered using print statements that this listener **DOES NOT RUN** with the *modified* version of `activate()` but it **DOES** run with the *original* version of activate().

I have no idea why this is the case and I can't see why this would be. I expect the listener to run with the original and modified activate() method.

Can anyone help me identify why this isn't the case?

Answer (score 0):

Summary of the issue:
activate() does not actually contain any async code. Adding an await means that SelectMultipleInitial, SelectMultipleLoading, SelectMultipleActivated are not emitted immediately after init() is called, which means there is not enough time for SelectMultipleView build() method to be called, so BlocListener has not been inserted into widget tree yet, resulting in listener not being able to respond to any states.

Solution:
Moved BlocListener to initState()

```
class _SelectMultipleViewState extends State<SelectMultipleView>

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // only listening to state here since activate() is NOT async
    final selectMultipleCubitState = context.read<SelectMultipleCubit>().state;
    if (selectMultipleCubitState is SelectMultipleActivated) {
      // this code should only run once, when the SelectMultipleView is setup
      // currently SelectMultipleActivated is only emitted once so it is fine
      final initiallySelectedListItem =
          selectMultipleCubitState.initiallySelectedItem;
      final restOfListItems = selectMultipleCubitState.items;
      // adding initially selected item to currentlySelectedListItems
      currentlySelectedListItemsNotifier.value.add(initiallySelectedListItem);
      // adding initially selected item to allItems first
      allItems.add(initiallySelectedListItem);
      // adding rest of folder contents to allItems
      allItems.addAll(restOfListItems);
    }
  }
```